# How to limit plesk user with SSH access only to his own webspace

Tags: ssh, permissions, plesk, chroot

I have created a Parallels plesk panel webspace and allowed SSH access:

1. In plesk go to the webspace
2. Websites & domains tab
3. Web hosting access
4. In *Access to the server over SSH* select `/bin/sh`

I connected by SSH and I realised I can go everywhere in the server and create files.

I would like to limit the SSH access just to the user directory.

I [read about `chroot`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208960/how-to-restrict-a-user-to-one-folder-and-not-allow-them-to-move-out-his-folder). Do you think it is the solution? There isn't a way to configure directly in Plesk?

Comment: Not a programming question - try [sf] ?

Comment: I did and they close it. Seems [server fault is not the place](http://serverfault.com/tags/plesk/info) for it

Comment: OK - did you read the suggestions in the [linked answer](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8094/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was as easy as select:

*Access to the server over SSH*: `/bin/bash` (chrooted)

[image]